# Removing space around tabular columns set with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

OK, first off, this table is horrendous looking and desperately needs help.

But what I'd really like to know is how to eliminate some of the extra white space between the columns set with `S` in the `tabular` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

Areas:\par
\sisetup{table-figures-decimal=4,table-auto-round,table-number-alignment=center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%%
\begin{tabular}{l
                >{$}r<{=$}
                S[table-figures-decimal=1,table-space-text-pre=]
                >{$}r<{=$}
                S}%'
   Area of region I:   & 4                    & 4    & \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot 4=         & 4           \\
   Area of region II:  & 8                    & 8    & 1\times 8                           & 8           \\
   Area of region III: & 6-3.5                & 2.5  & 2 \times 3 - \dfrac{1}{2}(1.5)^2\pi & 2.465708265 \\
   Area of region IV   & 35                   & 35   & 5\times 7                           & 35          \\
   Area of region V:   & 6.5                  & 6.5  & \dfrac{1}{2} (2)^2\pi               & 6.283185307 \\\hline
   Total               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 56.0 &                                     & 55.78990357
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Incidentally, I'm using `\multicolumn` in the last row to prevent the equal sign from showing up there.  Is there a better hack to eliminating, temporarily, material set for between the columns?  Since this is really a second question I could post it separately if that's better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `table-alignment=<choice>` with some small kerning in between like

```
@{\!}S[table-figures-decimal=1,table-space-text-pre=,table-alignment=left]
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

Areas:\par
\sisetup{table-figures-decimal=4,table-auto-round,table-number-alignment=center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%%
\begin{tabular}{l
                >{$}r<{=$}
                @{\!}S[table-figures-decimal=1,table-space-text-pre=,table-alignment=left]
                >{$}r<{=$}
                @{\!}S[table-alignment=left]}%'
   Area of region I:   & 4                    & 4    & \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot 4         & 4           \\
   Area of region II:  & 8                    & 8    & 1\times 8                           & 8           \\
   Area of region III: & 6-3.5                & 2.5  & 2 \times 3 - \dfrac{1}{2}(1.5)^2\pi & 2.465708265 \\
   Area of region IV   & 35                   & 35   & 5\times 7                           & 35          \\
   Area of region V:   & 6.5                  & 6.5  & \dfrac{1}{2} (2)^2\pi               & 6.283185307 \\\hline
   Total               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 56.0 &                                     & 55.78990357
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the kerning to your liking in `@{\!}`.

For your second question, I feel that `\multicolumn` is the best answer IMO. But Somebody may have a better hack.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure you want to align the numbers to the decimal point. But here's how you can improve the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

Areas:\par
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\sisetup{table-figures-decimal=4,table-auto-round}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  >{$}r<{={}$}
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.1]
  @{\hspace{3em}}
  >{$}r<{={}$}
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.4]
  @{}
}%'
Area of region I:   & 4     & 4    & \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot 4          & 4           \\
Area of region II:  & 8     & 8    & 1\times 8                           & 8           \\
Area of region III: & 6-3.5 & 2.5  & 2 \times 3 - \dfrac{1}{2}(1.5)^2\pi & 2.465708265 \\
Area of region IV   & 35    & 35   & 5\times 7                           & 35          \\
Area of region V:   & 6.5   & 6.5  & \dfrac{1}{2} (2)^2\pi               & 6.283185307 \\
\midrule
Total               &       & 56.0 &                                     & 55.78990357
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here's a different version without alignment on the decimal point; note that it needs the `collcell` package:

```
%% add in the preamble
\usepackage{collcell}
\newcommand{\bnum}[1]{\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=4]{#1}}

%% the table
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  >{$}r<{={}$}
  @{}
  >{\collectcell\num}l<{\endcollectcell}
  @{\hspace{3em}}
  >{$}r<{={}$}
  @{}
  >{\collectcell\bnum}l<{\endcollectcell}
  @{}
}%'
Area of region I:   & 4     & 4    & \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot 4         & 4           \\
Area of region II:  & 8     & 8    & 1\cdot 8                           & 8           \\
Area of region III: & 6-3.5 & 2.5  & 2 \cdot 3 - \dfrac{1}{2}(1.5)^2\pi & 2.465708265 \\
Area of region IV   & 35    & 35   & 5\cdot 7                           & 35          \\
Area of region V:   & 6.5   & 6.5  & \dfrac{1}{2} (2)^2\pi              & 6.283185307 \\
\midrule
Total               &       & 56.0 &                                    & 55.78990357
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah!  I'm not quite yet in the habit of using `booktabs`.

Comment: Care to elaborate why you wouldn't align on the decimal?

Comment: @A.Ellett It makes the whole thing very unbalanced.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm really not happy at all with the way this table looks.  It's very ugly.  :(

Comment: @A.Ellett I added a different version for comparison